# Viewing data types of columns in query result

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to see the data types of values in a query result in SQL Developer? I've got a query that I'm going to run in Java, and I need to know what the data types of the different columns are so I can read the `ResultSet` properly (using SQL Developer to debug the queries). I don't want to have to open all of the separate tables individually in order to see the type of the one or two columns I'm retrieving.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not calling `ResultSet.getMetaData()` to get a `ResultSetMetaData` object that tells you, among other things, the data types of all the columns in the result set?

Comment: I'm putting the values from the `ResultSet` into a `HashMap`, which is then compared to another `HashMap` built from a different data source (in this case, a SOAP response). Thus, I want to know what the types are at write-time so I can make sure that they match the types of the corresponding values in the other `HashMap`. (both are `HashMap<String, Object>`)